# Como Solucinar Error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy trabajando en un sistema de venta  tengo este error y no consigo solución

agradecería su apoyo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]